# PIL - can't change pixel values after converting type of image from L to F - AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'data'

Tags: python-imaging-library

I have an `"L"` type image that I converted to float `"F"`. I get an error when trying to change its pixel values after conversion. Below is a snippet.

```
a = mnist_images[i].convert(mode="F")
a = a.point(lambda j: 0)
```

And the error message

```
<ipython-input-45-f89cda3cf30e> in generate_moving_mnist(shape, seq_len, seqs, num_sz, nums_per_image)
     86                 b=mnist_images[i].point(lambda j: 0)
     87                 a=mnist_images[i].convert(mode="F")#.point(lambda j: 0)
---> 88                 a = a.point(lambda j: 0)
     89 
     90                 # paste the mnist_images[i] at position[i] on the current canvas

~\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py in point(self, lut, mode)
   1572                 # UNDONE wiredfool -- I think this prevents us from ever doing
   1573                 # a gamma function point transform on > 8bit images.
-> 1574                 scale, offset = _getscaleoffset(lut)
   1575                 return self._new(self.im.point_transform(scale, offset))
   1576             # for other modes, convert the function to a table

~\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py in _getscaleoffset(expr)
    483 def _getscaleoffset(expr):
    484     stub = ["stub"]
--> 485     data = expr(_E(stub)).data
    486     try:
    487         (a, b, c) = data  # simplified syntax

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'data'
```

I am able to change the pixel values if I do not convert the image type i.e. the line below on its own works just fine.

```
b = mnist_images[i].point(lambda j: 0)
```

I am currently using a workaround but I think its quite slow

```
a=mnist_images[i].copy()
a=a.convert(mode="F")
  for row in range(a.size[0]):
    for col in range(a.size[1]):
      a.putpixel((row, col), new_pixel_value)
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears from line 1581 of `PIL/Image.py` that the `point()` function is not supported on type `"F"` float images:

```
if self.mode == "F":
    # FIXME: _imaging returns a confusing error message for this case
    raise ValueError("point operation not supported for this mode")
```

If you would care to say what you are actually trying to do, I can maybe suggest a workaround.

Comment: Thank you, I realize that too. I am currently using a workaround (edited my post). I copy the PIL image into a new one then loop through the rows and column. It is not efficient but its sufficient in the meantime.

I am just trying to do some operation on each pixel.

Comment: If you are just trying to set all pixels to a single, solid colour, you can use `Image.paste(newColour)` https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#the-image-class

Comment: I'm not trying to set all pixels to a single color. It was just a short example. I am doing some computation over a neighbour. But its fine I need only run through the entire dataset one time. And thank you.